# How can I post multiple object with form data via django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

One company delivers multiple routes. How can I post the data via DRF?

There is an ImageField in DeliveryCompany

```python
class DeliveryCompany(models.Model):
    CompanyName = models.CharField("CRegNo", max_length=50, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    Address = models.CharField("CName", max_length=100, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    CompanyLogo = models.ImageField( default=None, null=True, blank=True)
 

class DeliveryRoute(models.Model):
    Delivery = models.ForeignKey(DeliveryCompany, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True)
    RouteFrom = models.CharField("RouteFrom", max_length=100, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    RouteTo = models.CharField("RouteTo", max_length=100, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
```

```html
class DeliveryCompanySerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    deliveryRoute = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = DeliveryCompany
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        routes_data = validated_data.pop('routes')
        delCom_obj = DeliveryCompany.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for route in routes_data:
            DeliveryRoute.objects.create(DeliveryCompany=DeliveryCompany, **routes_data)
        return delCom_obj

    def get_deliveryRoute(self, obj):
        return DeliveryRouteSerializers(obj.deliveryroute_set.all(), many=True).data
```

Comment: are you trying to have one form that can post a delivery company and multiple associated delivery routes ? also show your serializers code too

Comment: Yes, wanna post a delivery company and multiple delivery routes associated with it in a single post.

Comment: as I said before, need to see your serializers. also do you intend on creating new Delivery Routes when posting the delivery company or would those be already created before ?